Expected number of rolls and attempts to win a Dice Game with restarting rules
Recently I came across an interesting YouTube video. The author discusses a game, where you win if you can guess $8$ consecutive fair coin tosses correctly, and how we can eventually reduce the problem of finding the expected number of throws ($T$) until you win to finding the hitting time for the final state in an 8-state Markov chain. The author gives us an example of how this expected number can be computed, but does not explicitly derive a closed-form expression for it in case of an $n$-state Markov chain. Judging by the outcomes, I assume that the expected number of total throws, for a chain of $n$ rolls, in this very problem setting is given as:
$$
\mathbb{E}[T]=2\cdot(2^n-1)
$$
although I haven't made an attempt to prove it yet.
I decided to think of this problem in a general sense:

Assume a sequence $\mathbf{X}^{(\tau)}=\{X^{(\tau)}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of random variables, where each $X^{(\tau)}_i$ is an outcome of a fair $k$-sided die roll, assume also that all throws are independent. Now let's say that we are playing a game with an unlimited number of attempts: at each attempt ($\tau$) your aim is to guess the outcomes $X_i^{(\tau)}$ of $n$ consecutive rolls correctly. If all your guesses are correct, you win and the game stops, but if at any throw (including the $n$-th) your guess doesn't match the actual outcome of a die roll, you have to start anew at attempt $\tau+1$.

Question 1.: What is the expected number of attempts you'll have to make until you win?
Question 2.: What is the expected total number of rolls you'll have to make until you win?
Obviously, the probability of winning at the start of any given attempt is $k^{-n}$. Actually, since in our case the order in which we make correct guesses matters, as far as I understand, we cannot quite call the number of rolls per attempt a Binomial RV, and so for any number $m\leq n$ of consecutive successful guesses, the probability to have a "strike" of $m$ should be $k^{-m}$.
Now, how can we explicitly derive the closed-form expressions for the two expected values in question?
Another (rather random) side question is, can you think of any extension to the above problem, which makes it even more interesting/challenging?
Thank you in advance for your contribution!

Question 1 (expected number of attempts) simply sets up a geometric random variable with parameter $k^{-n}$ and expectation $k^n$

@Henry, you are absolutely right! Just it's the 2nd question, not the first one: I actually came to the same conclusion myself after writing the corresponding probability to "win" at any trial, since we can treat attempts as Bernoulli trials, so now the question is about the total number of rolls :)

Question 1 (expected number of attempts) simply sets up a geometric random variable with parameter $k^{-n}$ and expectation $k^n$, made up of an expected $k^n-1$ failed attempts and $1$ successful attempt.
The successful attempt requires $n$ throws, while each failed attempt requires an expected $\dfrac{1\frac{k-1}{k}+2\frac{k-1}{k}\frac1{k}+3\frac{k-1}{k}\frac1{k^2}+\cdots+ n\frac{k-1}{k}\frac1{k^{n-1}}}{\frac{k-1}{k}+\frac{k-1}{k}\frac{1}{k} +\frac{k-1}{k}\frac1{k^2}+\cdots+ \frac{k-1}{k}\frac1{k^{n-1}}} $ $= \dfrac{k^{n+1}-nk-k+n}{(k^n-1)(k-1)}$ number of throws, conditioned on the attempt being a failure.
This makes the answer to Question 2 (expected total number of throws) $(k^n-1)\frac{k^{n+1}-nk-k+n}{(k^n-1)(k-1)}+n$, which simplifies to $$\dfrac{k(k^n-1)}{k-1}$$ and you can do some simple checks:

when $n=1$ it gives $k$, the same as Q1 as then every attempt has $1$ throw;
when $k=2$ it gives $2(2^n-1)$, as you observed.


This answer, which when written as $k+k^2+\cdots +k^n$, is an example of what I thought was called Conway's algorithm

Thank you for your answer! Can you please explain me how do you get the denominator? I mean, I understand how we get the numerator - it's just all the variants how we can fail after $m$ throws for $m\in\mathbb{N}_{[1,n]}$, but not the denominator..

If you see the numerator as $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} (i+1) \times P(i\text{ successes})\times P(1 \text{ failure})$ then the denominator is just  $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} P(i\text{ successes})\times P(1 \text{ failure})$ as the probability of failing an attempt.  The denominator is equal to $1-k^{-n}$.  You need to divide by this to get a result conditional on a failed atempt.

Thank you for clarification!
